# what is the logic of this keyword in js inside method in method?

Tags: javascript, web, function-prototypes

Could anyone tell "this" keyword in js .. 
I looked examples . There is a point that I can't understand.

```
   A.B=function()
    {
      this.x(5); // this refers to prototype of A.B
    }


   A.B.prototype= { 
    x:function(p)
    { this.a(p);  // this refers to prototype of A.B again  
                  // but I expect that this refers to protoype of x ???  

     }, 
        a:function(p){ return p;}
     }
```

Comment: read this: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: In both cases it refers to the `B` instance, so you can call `a`/`x` on it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: `this` is determined at **runtime** not at parse/definition time. Solely by looking at the definition you cannot tell what `this` will refer to. It all depends on **how** the function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call a method:

```
a.b.c.d();
```

then `this` is `a.b.c` inside of the method (everything except the final function name).

If you call a constructor:

```
var x = new Something();
```

then `this` is a new fresh object inside of Something().

Everywhere else `this` is the global object (which is the same as `window` in the browser).

`this` is never a prototype. This can **have** a prototype.

In your example:

```
A.B = function() {
  this.x(5);
}
```

`this` is `A` (which doesn't have to be a prototype of `A.B`) if that method is called as `A.B()` - and is a new object if that method is called as `new A.B()`.